# How To Get Content From Array Code

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have script json to aray like this

```
array (
  'status_code' => 200,
  'status_txt' => 'OK',
  'data' => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://bit*ly/2jc5mvr',
    'hash' => '2jc5mvr',
    'global_hash' => 'CuJU',
    'long_url' => 'http://github.com/',
    'new_hash' => 1,
  ),
)
```

how to get short url result from that's array ? i have try this code

```
$json['url']
```

But, Not Work.

Comment: try this **echo $json['data']['url'];**

Comment: what's a `$json`? Where it is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
$json['data']['url']
```

You're trying to get `'url'` from the top-level array, but you need to get it from the sub-level array (`'data'`).

Comment: It should work. This one is working fine for me and is the right solution.

Comment: @FaraazFarzainPermadi Make sure your array is called `$json` and your array looks how you'd expect it to with [`var_dump`](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Also, could you send me the error message that you're getting. "it still does not work" isn't terribly specific. Further than that, I don't think I can help you. I can't debug all your code for you.